# Android studio: App crashing -

Tags: android

This is the java code for changing background color on user click.On running on device it says  "Unfortunately app has stopped working".

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    RelativeLayout myLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    Button redbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button bluebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    redbtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
    );
    bluebtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
    );
    myLayout.addView(redbtn);  myLayout.addView(bluebtn);
    //setContentView(myLayout);
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat if its crashing.

Comment: what's the reason of crash? paste your error log

Comment: most of the time in logcat you can find the line that your error rise and the reason of that

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout myLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    Button redbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Button bluebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    redbtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
    );
    bluebtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
    );
    myLayout.addView(redbtn);  myLayout.addView(bluebtn);
    //setContentView(myLayout);
}
```

Comment: Declaring Layout inside onCreate() throws error and says it must be declared as "final".I have tried out making it final too but error is the same.

Comment: can you post log cat please